# Loading content from remote site doesn't work, but why?

Tags: php, json, parsing, dom

I'm still working on this catalogue for a client, which loads images from a remote site via PHP and the Simple DOM Parser.

```
// Code excerpt from http://internetvolk.de/fileadmin/template/res/scrape.php, this is just one case of a select

$subcat = $_GET['subcat'];
$url = "http://pinesite.com/meubelen/index.php?".$subcat."&lang=de";
$html = file_get_html(html_entity_decode($url));
$iframe = $html->find('iframe',0);
$url2 = $iframe->src;
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
$fullurl = "http://pinesite.com/meubelen/".$url2;
$html2 = file_get_html(html_entity_decode($fullurl));
$pagecount = 1;
$titles = $html2->find('.tekst');
$images = $html2->find('.plaatje');
$output='';
$i=0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
$item['title'] = $titles[$i]->find('p',0)->plaintext;
$imagePath = $image->find('img',0)->src;
$item['thumb'] = resize("http://pinesite.com".str_replace('thumb_','',$imagePath),array("w"=>225, "h"=>162));
$item['image'] = 'http://pinesite.com'.str_replace('thumb_','',$imagePath);
$fullurl2 = "http://pinesite.com/meubelen/prog/showpic.php?src=".str_replace('thumb_','',$imagePath)."&taal=de";
$html3 = file_get_html($fullurl2);
$item['size'] = str_replace(' &nbsp;','',$html3->find('td',1)->plaintext);
unset($html3);
$output[] = $item;
$i++;
}
if (count($html2->find('center')) > 1) {
// ok, multi-page here, let's find out how many there are
$pagecount = count($html2->find('center',0)->find('a'))-1;
for ($i=1;$i<$pagecount; $i++) {
$startID = $i*20;
$newurl = html_entity_decode($fullurl."&beginrec=".$startID);
$html3 = file_get_html($newurl);
$titles = $html3->find('.tekst');
$images = $html3->find('.plaatje');
$a=0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
$item['title'] = $titles[$a]->find('p',0)->plaintext;
$item['image'] = 'http://pinesite.com'.str_replace('thumb_','',$image->find('img',0)->src);
$item['thumb'] = resize($item['image'],array("w"=>225, "h"=>150));
$output[] = $item;
$a++;
}
$html3->clear();
unset ($html3);
}
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

So what it should do (and does with some categories): Output the images, the titles and the the thumbnails from this page: http://pinesite.com

This works, for example, if you pass it a "?function=images&subcat=antiek", but not if you pass it a "?function=images&subcat=stoelen". I don't even think it's a problem with the remote page, so there has to be an error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm..trying to state the obvious maybe but 'stoele'?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it should be "stoelen".

Comment: Yeah, that what just a typo in asking the question, it is 'stoelen', but it still doesn't work, it just outputs ''.

Comment: ok. Wrong method maybe but using the wrong value might have caused his problem, and could therefore have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my code was completely fine, it was a missing space in the HTML of the remote site that got the Simple PHP DOM Parser to not recognize the iframe I was looking for. I fixed it on my end by running a str_replace on the code first to replace the faulty code.

I know it's a dirty solution, but it works :)